# Spring boot set session time by date

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-session

Is it possible to set the spring session timeout with date time and not in minutes? In our production we work from 05:00 am to 10:00 pm and the current session timeout is set to 1080 minutes. And after the 18 hours the session was destroyed for all clients. But actual the sessions were destroy between the production work time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible. My solution was to set the session timeout to -1. This value means, that the users are never logged off automatically.